# how to run Play2.5.x in sbt as daemon?

Tags: sbt

I attempt to deploy my Play project in a test environment by `sbt run`.
It could be easy test and update source code inner a team.
But the sbt(v0.13.15) process and Play process be closed when I leave the ssh session.
I have attempt with:
`setsid sbt "run -Dhttp.port=9001 -Dhttp.address=192.168.1.230" &`

`nohup sbt "run  -Dhttp.port=9001 -Dhttp.address=192.168.1.230"  &`

`sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal "run  -Dhttp.port=9004 -Dhttp.address=192.168.1.230" &`

`setsid nohup sbt "run -Dhttp.port=9001 -Dhttp.address=192.168.1.230" &`

Hope some help.Thanks